# Windows Store not disabled after Policy Editor change

Tags: windows, windows-10, group-policy

I've attempted to disable the Windows Store using the Policy Editor. After restarting several times, it starts up and runs constantly anyway - proof of Policy Editor:

[image: proof of policy editor settings]

Does anyone know of a reason this wouldn't be working or another way to disable the store? It's consuming a ton of my system resources constantly.

Comment: The policy is only applicable to Enterprise and Education editions of Windows 10+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know of a reason this wouldn't be working or another way to disable the store? It's consuming a ton of my system resources constantly.

The policy only applies to Windows 10/11 Education and Enterprise editions. However, a suspended application that is NOT running and/or suspended, uses little to no resources. If you want to disable Windows Store on Windows 10 Professional or Windows 11 Professional you will upgrade to a supported edition.

> Not supported on Windows 10 Pro, starting with version 1511. For more info, see [Knowledge Base article #3135657](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/group-policy/cannot-disable-microsoft-store)